# Searching for solution to end re-voting with Android voting app

Tags: android, vote

I am working an an Android app where users can create a contest, list partisipants and receive a code. Other users can enter this code, see the partisipants and vote on one. We now have it where the user enters an email address to vote and no two email addresses can vote on the same contest. But the user can bypass this by simply entering an alternate email address or a giberish email address (sfhf@dheg.com). Does anyone have any suggestions about how to solve this issue?

The paradox seems to be that we can make it low security and easy to use, or we can make it high security (confirm the email address via auto responded) but then its laborious to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well in case of android you can use **GCM ID or Device ID** its unique to device and hence no-one else would be able to vote from same device (if that fits your use case).

[How to get Unique Device ID ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/1503130)